# How to get and analyse pdf file with blob url using Cypress

Tags: pdf, automation, cypress, blob

I am working on automation framework for a web application. It based on Cypress.
On one of the application pages I have to download a dynamically generated PDF file and to analyse its content. The URL to the PDF file is a blob URL that looks like *blob:https://....*. When I click on the link it just opens it in the new browser tab. Since it's Cypress I can't work with the new windows. When I try to call cy.visit with the blob URL I receive:

> Error: Invalid protocol: blob:

I am aware of the Blob library in the Cypress, but it's hard to me to understand from documentation how it can be used in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could use `cy.request()` to obtain the pdf content

```js
cy.get(pdf-link-element)
  .invoke('attr', 'href')
  .then(href => {
    cy.request(href).then(pdfContent => {
      ...
    })
  })
```

That would get you around the window opening, but the next question is how to work with `pdfContent` which would be a bit raw.

Maybe `cy.writeFile()` it to `/cypress/downloads` and use a pdf parsing library to get something useful to test.